# Exact pattern match in unstructered dataset (text or CSV file)

Tags: regex, r, grepl

I need to find out the best way to match an exact pattern combination of symbols, letters and digits from a CSV or text file with very unstructured dataset.

I need to extract exactly the pattern “`BR1*********`” (`BR1` + exactly 9 digits), which is in the middle of row :61: and the pattern “`?54***`” (`?54` + exactly 3 digits), which always at the end of row :61:.

Both 2 patterns are repetitive but with different digit combinations.

I have tried with `grep` and `grepl` so far without success. I receive as a result always the whole row, where this pattern is approximately matched but not the exact match of symbols and digits.

Below is a little part of the dataset:

```
:11:hgttu6576575?//80&&80980jhkhkhlkhkh  gjdggfjsdf?kjhkuhsfk778798978**&
:27:jhkjhuiy867tjhfsh/.>?kjklh8ggdhkotrdkhofkhodkgj
:61:kjljlkfjsdlBR1678899458iyuyugug7787?>?///uhhiuyi
jhkhkjhiy878697y8hukjlu97 ??///khiuy8oujhuhijk?54160
:11:hgggdgf79878yiuhlkhkh  gjdggfhuihiuhuiou89 ioiojsdf?kjhkuhsfk778798978**&
:27:jhkjhuiy867tjhfsh/.>?kjklh8ggdhkotrdkhofkhodkgj
:61:kjljlkfjsdlBR1234885765iyuyugug7787?>?///uhhiuyi
jhkhkjhiy878697y8hukjlu97 ??///khiuy8oujhuhijk?54190
```

Comment: Could you show `dput(head(lines))`?  Also, can you check whether the solution works for a smaller subset of dataset? ie. `lines1 <- head(lines,20)`

Comment: Hi @akrun, thanks for asking this.The problem is that it is a huge file (File.txt) with thousands of rows/lines and I cannot use lines<-readLines(textConnection("") and copy and paste all the lines in the textConnection(""). Any idea is highly appreciated.

Comment: I am not talking about posting the full file.  You can read the file using `lines <- readLines("file.txt")` and then post the first few lines using `dput(head(lines))`.  Also have you run the code on a subset of dataset.

Answer (score 3):

`strapplyc` in the gsubfn package can be used to extract these portions.  Here we extract the entire string or if you only want the digits part place parentheses around the digits part, e.g. `pat1 <- "BR(1\\d{9})"`

```
library(gsubfn)

pat1 <- "BR1\\d{9}"
pat2 <- "[?]54\\d{3}$"

strapplyc(lines, pat1, simplify = c)
## [1] "BR1678899458" "BR1234885765"

strapplyc(lines, pat2, simplify = c)
## [1] "?54160" "?54190"
```

or both at once:

```
strapplyc(lines, paste(pat1, pat2, sep = "|"), simplify = c)
## [1] "BR1678899458" "?54160"       "BR1234885765" "?54190"
```

Use `grep` with the same patterns if you want the line numbers (i.e. first line is 1, second line is 2, etc.) instead of the values themselves.

**Added** It should not be a problem to read the file in if there are merely a few thousand lines:

```
lines <- readLines("File.txt")
```

If it really is too large you could read use `read.csv.sql` in the sqldf package which in one line of code can read setup an sqlite database read the file into it and then extract a subset of lines into R. Here we have assumed that there are no `?` in the file but if there are use some other separator 
not in the file:

```
library(sqldf)

lines <- read.csv.sql("File.txt", header = FALSE, sep = "?", 
      sql = "select * from file where V1 like '%BR1%' or V1 like '%54%'")
# now use strapplyc as above
```

Comment: Hi @G.Grothendieck, thanks for sharing your solution.The problem is that it is a huge file (File.txt) with thousands of rows/lines and I cannot use lines<-readLines(textConnection("") and copy and paste all the lines in the textConnection(""). Any idea is highly appreciated.

Comment: See discussion added at end of answer.

Comment: Hi @G.Grothendieck, thank you so much for sharing this and moreover for the efforts! It was very helpful and useful to see the task from other perspective.Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
   library(stringr)
   unlist(str_extract_all(lines, "(BR1\\d{9})|(\\?54\\d{3})"))
   #[1] "BR1678899458" "?54160"        "BR1234885765" "?54190"
```

#### Update

If it is a huge file, you could use `stringi`, which will be faster

```
  library(stringi)
  na.omit(unlist(stri_extract_all_regex(lines, "(BR1\\d{9})|(\\?54\\d{3})")))
  #[1] "BR1678899458" "?54160"       "BR1234885765" "?54190"
```

#### data

```
lines <- readLines(textConnection(':11:hgttu6576575?//80&&80980jhkhkhlkhkh  gjdggfjsdf?kjhkuhsfk778798978**&
 :27:jhkjhuiy867tjhfsh/.>?kjklh8ggdhkotrdkhofkhodkgj
 :61:kjljlkfjsdlBR1678899458iyuyugug7787?>?///uhhiuyi jhkhkjhiy878697y8hukjlu97 ??///khiuy8oujhuhijk?54160
 :11:hgggdgf79878yiuhlkhkh  gjdggfhuihiuhuiou89 ioiojsdf?kjhkuhsfk778798978**&
 :27:jhkjhuiy867tjhfsh/.>?kjklh8ggdhkotrdkhofkhodkgj
 :61:kjljlkfjsdlBR1234885765iyuyugug7787?>?///uhhiuyi jhkhkjhiy878697y8hukjlu97 ??///khiuy8oujhuhijk?54190'))
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for sharing your solution. The result looks quite good. The problem is that it is a huge file (File.txt) (I should have mentioned this at the beginning) and I cannot use dat=readLines(textConnection(""), since there are thousands of lines in the txt.file 
So I tried it with:     
lines<-readLines("File.txt") 
library(stringr)
unlist(str_extract_all(lines, "(BR1\\d{9})|(\\?54\\d{3})"))

But it doesn't work I receive as a result character(0). Any idea how to do it with File.txt?

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing both alternatives for code. This made the trick :). Sorry, I realized that previously I have used the wrong file, but now it worked pretty good.                                                                library(stringr)
> unlist(str_extract_all(lines, "(BR1\\d{9})|(\\?54\\d{3})"))
[1] "BR1678899458" "?54160"       "BR1234885765" "?54190"       "BR1548812358" "?54195"       "BR1768834128" "?54199"

Answer (score 2):

```
dat <- readLines(textConnection(":11:hgttu6576575?//80&&80980jhkhkhlkhkh  gjdggfjsdf?kjhkuhsfk778798978**&
:27:jhkjhuiy867tjhfsh/.>?kjklh8ggdhkotrdkhofkhodkgj
:61:kjljlkfjsdlBR1678899458iyuyugug7787?>?///uhhiuyi
jhkhkjhiy878697y8hukjlu97 ??///khiuy8oujhuhijk?54160
:11:hgggdgf79878yiuhlkhkh  gjdggfhuihiuhuiou89 ioiojsdf?kjhkuhsfk778798978**&
:27:jhkjhuiy867tjhfsh/.>?kjklh8ggdhkotrdkhofkhodkgj
:61:kjljlkfjsdlBR1234885765iyuyugug7787?>?///uhhiuyi
jhkhkjhiy878697y8hukjlu97 ??///khiuy8oujhuhijk?54190"))

library(stringr)

unlist(str_match_all(dat, "(BR1[[:digit:]]{9})|(\\?54[[:digit:]]{3})"))
##  [1] "BR1678899458" "BR1678899458" ""             "?54160"      
##  [5] ""             "?54160"       "BR1234885765" "BR1234885765"
##  [9] ""             "?54190"       ""             "?54190"
```

If we knew more about the format you need this in, we could help you better.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your efforts and sharing your solution. Yes, you are completely right that the format is very important(I forgot to mention it,sorry about that). The problem is that it is a huge file (File.txt) and I cannot use dat=readLines(textConnection(""). So I tried it with:               dat<-readLines("File.txt") library(stringr)

unlist(str_match_all(dat, "(BR1[[:digit:]]{9})|(\\?54[[:digit:]]{3})"))                           
But it doesn't work. In the result both patterns should be matched at once since they are corresponding to each other always on row :61: Any idea?

Comment: Hi @hrbrmstr, I checked your code with the whole file "File.txt" and it worked.I realized that previously I have used a wrong file. As I need that both patterns are matched simultaniously for me the best solution is:lines<-readLines("File.txt")
> unlist(regmatches(lines, gregexpr('BR1\\d{9}|\\?54\\d{3}', lines)))
[1] "BR1678899458" "?54160"       "BR1234885765" "?54190"       "BR1548812358" "?54195"       "BR1768834128" "?54199"

Answer (score 2):

My reading of the natrual language description is that only 2 lines satisfy the requiremnt. The 4th line for instance does have a "?54nnn$" pattern but that line doesn't begin with ":61:":

```
dat=readLines(textConnection(":11:hgttu6576575?//80&&80980jhkhkhlkhkh  gjdggfjsdf?kjhkuhsfk778798978**&
:27:jhkjhuiy867tjhfsh/.>?kjklh8ggdhkotrdkhofkhodkgj
:61:kjljlkfjsdlBR1678899458iyuyugug7787?>?///uhhiuyi
jhkhkjhiy878697y8hukjlu97 ??///khiuy8oujhuhijk?54160
:11:hgggdgf79878yiuhlkhkh  gjdggfhuihiuhuiou89 ioiojsdf?kjhkuhsfk778798978**&
:27:jhkjhuiy867tjhfsh/.>?kjklh8ggdhkotrdkhofkhodkgj
:61:kjljlkfjsdlBR1234885765iyuyugug7787?>?///uhhiuyi
jhkhkjhiy878697y8hukjlu97 ??///khiuy8oujhuhijk?54190"))

> grep("^:61:.+(BR1\\d{9}|[?]54\\d{3}$)", dat)
#[1] 3 7
```

Modifying the test case to see if my pattern suggestion performs correctly for what I thought was the question:

```
> dat=readLines(textConnection(":11:hgttu6576575?//80&&80980jhkhkhlkhkh  gjdggfjsdf?kjhkuhsfk778798978**&
+ :27:jhkjhuiy867tjhfsh/.>?kjklh8ggdhkotrdkhofkhodkgj
+ :61:kjljlkfjsdlBR1678899458iyuyugug7787?>?///uhhiuyi
+ :61:jhkhkjhiy878697y8hukjlu97 ??///khiuy8oujhuhijk?54160
+ :11:hgggdgf79878yiuhlkhkh  gjdggfhuihiuhuiou89 ioiojsdf?kjhkuhsfk778798978**&
+ :27:jhkjhuiy867tjhfsh/.>?kjklh8ggdhkotrdkhofkhodkgj
+ :61:kjljlkfjsdlBR1234885765iyuyugug7787?>?///uhhiuyi
+ jhkhkjhiy878697y8hukjlu97 ??///khiuy8oujhuhijk?54190")
+ )
> grep("^:61:.+(BR1\\d{9}|[?]54\\d{3}$)", dat)
[1] 3 4 7
```

Comment: i read this `Learned R on my own` from your profile page. Which book did you followed?

Comment: My first book was "Modern Applied Statistics in S (2nd ed)? I probably should have picked up a good introductory text but there weren't really any of them at the time. After that I learned by reading postings to the Rhelp mailing list and then trying to answer them and if I couldn't, then running the code by the other contributors and breaking it apart line by line and reading the help pages and running the examples.

Comment: *running the code by the other contributors and breaking it apart line by line and reading the help pages and running the examples.* - I couldn't agree more.  That's how I've done most of my R learning

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for sharing your solution. The problem is that it is a huge file (File.txt) (I should have mantioned this at the beginning) and I cannot use dat=readLines(textConnection(""). So I tried it with:               dat<-readLines("File.txt")                               grep("^:61:.+(BR1\\d{9}|[?]54\\d{3}$)", dat)
But it doesn't work I receive as a result integer(0). Actually as a result both pattersn should be matched at once since they are corresponding to each other always on row :61: Any idea?

Comment: If the patterns are both on the same line then the pattern argument would just be formed by putting a variable length arbitrary match between the two patterns: `"^:61:.+BR1\\d{9}.+[?]54\\d{3}$"` . The `readlines()` function can take a file name argument,so unless the file size is in gigabytes that should not be a barrier.

Comment: @BondedDust Thank you for your feedback.You are absolutely right! The code works for the whole file with readLines as well.Thanks for sharing it.

Answer (score 2):

You can handle the extraction of these matches using base R.

```
> unlist(regmatches(lines, gregexpr('BR1\\d{9}|\\?54\\d{3}', lines)))
# [1] "BR1678899458" "?54160"       "BR1234885765" "?54190"
```

Comment: Start calling you "The Doctor" pretty soon

Comment: @hwnd. This is it! That made the trick! :) Thanks a million for sharing it.                               lines<-readLines("File.txt")
> unlist(regmatches(lines, gregexpr('BR1\\d{9}|\\?54\\d{3}', lines)))
[1] "BR1678899458" "?54160"       "BR1234885765" "?54190"       "BR1548812358" "?54195"       "BR1768834128" "?54199"